# proxy_pass в nginx и check origin в приложении

Tags: linux, nginx, сервер, proxy, proxypass

На одном хостинге размещено 2 приложения на разных портах (81 и 82). Nginx слушает 80-ый порт, в зависимости от поддомена запроса проксирует на нужное приложение. Например: `app1.domain.com` и `app2.domain.com`

Директивы `nginx` указаны:

- `proxy_pass: http://domain.com:81/events` - для запроса на `/events`, так как это URL для подключения к websocket'у, а для этого нужно добавить отдельные директивы
- `proxy_pass: http://domain.com:81/` - для всех остальных запросов

Первый вопрос:

В приложении используются websocket'ы, реализация в библиотеке по-умолчанию проверяет на совпадение заголовок Origin и URL запроса (вызывается функция `checkOrigin` в библиотеке `gorilla/websocket` в языке `Go`) - из-за чего запрос не проходит, так как Origin: `app1.domain.com/events`, а URL запроса: `domain.com:81/events`. Библиотека позволяет переопределить функцию `checkOrigin` таким образом, чтобы она всегда возвращала `true` и пропускала запрос. Но интересует, как проксировать запрос из nginx'a таким образом, чтобы не нужно было редактировать код самого приложения - то есть чтобы Origin совпадал с URL запроса.

Второй вопрос:

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в таком случае (`proxy_pass: http://domain.com/`) запрос лишний раз проходит через DNS, увеличивая задержку до ответа? Правильно ли я тогда понимаю, что лучше сделать `proxy_pass: http://localhost:81/` или добавить строку `127.0.0.1 domain.com` в `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $host;` обычно достаточно.

Comment: 2. Нет, dns запрашивается при старте (рестарте) nginx и ip-адрес кешируется. Но если всё происходит на одной машине то проще сразу написать `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется что достаточно написать примерно так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # другие директивы для /
    }

    location /events {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # другие директивы для /events
    }
}
```

Если все директивы `proxy_set_header` в обоих блоках сопадают, то можно их перенести в блок `server`.